# How to create a link for PDF file in Magento

Tags: magento2, link, download, download-link

How to create a link for a PDF file in Magento?

I have uploaded the PDF file to the catalog, how to create a hyperlink for download?

Answer (score 0):

You can take reference from the below link for creating custom download link in magento -

https://meetanshi.com/blog/create-custom-download-link-in-magento-2/